# Passando uma function com parâmetros no HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5, node.js, back-end

Eu estou tentando fazer um delete no meu backend ser chamado no HTML quando uma pessoa clicar em determinado botão.
Daí eu estou passando um script src, pro arquivo que tem essa function. E no onclick estou chamando essa function, assim:

```
const db = require('../backend/db')
const routes = require('./routes')

const ideas = db.run('SELECT * FROM ideas')

function deleteIdeia(id) {
    routes.delete(`/ideias/${id}`)
}

module.exports = deleteIdeia
```

e o onclick:

```
<button onclick="deleteIdeia(ideas.id)" />
```

E o delete no meu back:

```
delete(req, res) {
        const { id } = req.params

        db.run(`DELETE FROM ideas WHERE id = ?`, [id], function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err)

            console.log('DELETEI')
        })

        return res.redirect('/ideias')
   }
```

O probliema é que ele fala que a função deleteIdeia não foi definida.

PS: A função do backend estã funcionando direitinho, eu testei ele no INSOMNIA.

Comment: Como você está gerando esse html?

Comment: Com html mesmo. Um arquivo .html

Comment: Então você importou um js no padrão do node no html?

Comment: Isso, exatamente.

Comment: Verifica se o seu console gera algum erro quando carrega a página.

Comment: Não aparece nehum erro